# Code coverage для кода без юнит тестов

Tags: c#, отладка

В проекте большое кол-во логики сконцентрировано в обработчиках событий формы.

Для них юнит-тесты писать невозможно, только ручной прогон.

Существуют ли средства, позволяющие делать собирать информацию о Code Coverage во время тестового запуска программы (в т.ч. и с отладчиком),

Comment: Нужно для контроля "что я еще не протестировал"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Cтандартные утилиты для проверки покрытия лежат в `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools`. Через них же работает подсчет покрытия при прогоне тестов.

VSPerfMon.exe позволяет померять покрытие у чего угодно. Добавляете `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Team Tools\Performance Tools` в `%PATH%`, и выполняетe

```
vsinstr /coverage TestApp.exe
VSPerfCmd /Start:Coverage /Output:TestApp.coverage
VSPerfCmd /Launch:TestApp.exe (или просто TestApp.exe)
...протыкиваете приложение
VSPerfCmd /shutdown
```

После этого открываете TestApp.coverage студией.

[MSDN очень подробно, с примерами, расписаны все командные ключи](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/dd255420.aspx). Отладчик можно прицепить к уже запущенному приложению.